# apply returns multiple values instead of single value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `A` and `B`. `A` contains the following:

```
Title        Year
title1       2000
title2       2001
title3       NaN
```

while `B` contains the following:

```
Title        Year
title3       2002
```

I want to find all the `NaN` values in the `Year` column of dataframe A and replace them with the value of the `Year` column of dataframe B where the `Title` column of A and B match.Thus, the result should be:

```
Title        Year
title1       2000
title2       2001
title3       2002
```

I tried using `apply` through the following code:

```
def func(x):
    if np.isnan(A.Year):
        C = A.loc[A.Title == B.Title]
        return C.Year
    else:
        return A.Year

a.Year = a.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis = 1)
```

However, instead of putting `2002` in the `title3` row of `A`, what is there instead is `2 2002.0 Name: Year, dtype: float64`. How do I make it so that the output of the function is just a single value instead of a string of values?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with match by index values - so converted both columns `Title` to `index` first:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Title')
df2 = df2.set_index('Title')

df1['Year'] = df1['Year'].combine_first(df2['Year'])
print (df1)
          Year
Title         
title1  2000.0
title2  2001.0
title3  2002.0
```

If need update values (not only `NaN`s) use [`Series.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
print (df1)
    Title  Year
0  title1  2000
1  title2  2001
2  title3  2000 <- not important what is value here for Year

df1 = df1.set_index('Title')
df2 = df2.set_index('Title')

df1['Year'].update(df2['Year'])
print (df1)
        Year
Title       
title1  2000
title2  2001
title3  2002
```